# Memberdata as channel entries, showing amount empty fields in profile

Tags: zoo-visitor, solspace-user, profile-edit

We are setting up a system for members, and will be using a plugin for storing memberdata in a channel. We did not decide yet for Solspace User, Profile:edit (likely since we'll use Cartthrob) or Zoo-visitor.

One feature would be nice to implement, showing the amount of data in a profile.
With a message: 'you filled in x% of your profile.'
And a congratulation of course the moment they reach 100%.
I am interested in how to implement that, if possible.

Is there anyone that has done this?

Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst I'm keen not to see this site become a 'do-my-homework-for-me' -type thing, I quite fancied having a go at this and had both some spare time and magnanimity... so please try out [Perfect](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/perfect).

It's very basic at the moment, but let me know via the Devot:ee forum of any extra features you need to make it useful.

Comment: Was rather late accepting your answer, sorry..... But it works well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty simple with a custom add-on. Select all the profile fields for a member, see how many are not empty, and divide that by the total number of fields to get a percentage.

You may also want to group some fields together as one "value" when doing this calculation, depending on how specific your fields are.

But there is no add-on out there for this - you'll need to write it yourself.

Comment: Hi Derek, thanks for answering. Writing my own addon is something I have never done before. Maybe someone in the community is interested in it, just in case more people would like to use it?